# Display value with textbox

Tags: php

I created two textboxes in php:

```
 <input type="text" name="uzytkownik" value="uzytkownik" style="position: absolute; left: 780px; top: 290px; "/>
<input type="text2" name="haslo" value="" style="position: absolute; left: 780px; top: 330px; "/>
```

And I would like to display the value within textbox "uzytkownik".

```
<?php
  $user = $_POST['uzytkownik'];
  echo $user;
?>
```

But it is not working, "$user" is empty.

Comment: Please edit, you lost the php code.

Comment: Most likely your inputs are not within a `<form>` or the forms method is not `POST`.

Comment: Please include your form tags so that we can confirm that your form method is indeed POST and that the form is in the correct format..

Comment: Is the form is submitted by using the "POST" method, or the "GET" method ?

Answer (score 2):

You've created the following :

```
<input type="text2"
```

Type "text2" doesn't exist in HTML.
It should be :

```
<input type="text"
```

Moreover, the correct code will be :

```
<input type="text" id="uzytkownik" name="uzytkownik" value="uzytkownik" style="position: absolute; left: 780px; top: 290px;" />
<input type="text" id="haslo" name="haslo" value="" style="position: absolute; left: 780px; top: 330px; " />
```

Comment: That's correct for the second input but the one he is trying to use `uzytkownik` is a valid text input.

Comment: Yes @MrCode, the first one is correct ;)

Comment: IMHO the syntax error on the html side should not effect the values being posted to the php server.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct this error it should be `<input type="text"` not `<input type="text2"`

and place your elements inside the `form`, make sure that the `form` method is just like  `method="post"`

Answer (score 0):

Put input tag in a form with action script and method 'post'.

Comment: This mi my complet code:

Comment: Try with $_REQUEST instead of $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<input type="text" name="uzytkownik" value="<?php echo $_POST['uzytkownik'];?>" style="position: absolute; left: 780px; top: 290px; "/>
<input type="text" name="haslo" value="<?php echo $_POST['haslo'];?>" style="position: absolute; left: 780px; top: 330px; "/>'
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all, as many others have noticed, the second input box has a syntax error. This html syntax error should how ever not effect the data being posted for the first input box.

You will need to have your input boxes wrapped in a form in order to be able to submit it, thus I believe your error would be in the method used by your form (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp).

Change this to POST in order to retrieve the values from the `$_POST` variable.

You will also need to change the input type of the second input box in order for its values to be submitted to your server.

Just for interest sake, the `$_REQUEST` global var contains data for both `GET` and `POST` requests and can be used when not sure what http method was used, but I would not recommend using this except for debugging.

```
<form action="url_to_your_php_script.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="uzytkownik" name="uzytkownik" value="uzytkownik" style="position: absolute; left:780px; top: 290px; "/>
    <input type="text" id="haslo" name="haslo" value="" style="position: absolute; left: 780px; top: 330px; "/>
</form>
```

And for your php code (I'd recommend first checking if the value exists in the array, before attempting to access it):

```
<?php 
if (array_key_exists("uzytkownik", $_POST)) {
    echo $_POST["uzytkownik"];
} else {
    echo "No value found";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using a good editor like NetBeans or Notepad++.

You'll see such errors immediately.